# how to create observable from blazor element's click events

Tags: blazor, reactive, rx.net

```
@* test.razor *@

<button>click</button>
```

I have a button in a razor component, and I want to create an Observable from it's click event which I don't know how to do. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you mean how to create an Observable from System.Reactive that calls OnNext() when you click the button?

Comment: @LeeMcPherson Yes.  In rx.js,  I can use `Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')` to create an Observable. In rx.net, I don't know how to do the  same thing with blazor.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ReactiveUI (on Nuget).

C# ViewModel constructor

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
   public ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit> MyCommand {get;}

   public MyViewModel()
   {
       MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create((_)=> // do some work);
   }
}
```

MyComponent.razor

```
@inherits ReactiveComponentBase<MyViewModel>

<button @onclick=@(()=> ViewModel.MyCommand.Execute().Subscribe() )>click</button>
```

#### OR

If you refuse to use ReactiveUI (it's good!), you can make your own subject.  Just make sure you dispose of everything properly.

MyComponent.razor

```
<button @onclick=@(()=> command.OnNext(Unit.Default) )>click</button>

@code{
   private Subject<Unit> command = new Subject<Unit>();
   public IObservable<Unit> Command => command.AsObservable();
}
```

If there were an event to handle like in regular C# based UI, then we could use the `Observable.FromEvent` pattern, but Blazor doesn't do events like this.  UIs built with C# (UWP, Xamarin) use the command pattern instead.  This is why there is a `ReactiveCommand` in ReactiveUI.  A UI button will generally understand how to deal with something that implements `ICommand` which gives it the ability to disable itself when the command is inactive. (i.e. when you haven't finished processing the command)  Not many Blazor components can deal with ICommand directly yet, but you can manually have it work with them.  BlazorFluentUI has buttons that work with Commands. (This is the component library I work on.)

Comment: Hey Lee, is there a way to achieve the same in ASP Core / views

Comment: I don't think so. ReacriveUI is very UI focused. Blazor is only somewhat compatible with it. I think asp net views are almost entirely server side, right? I'd ask in the ReactiveUI slack channel to see if someone else knows.